# Create Composite Key on Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I am working on a basic collaborative filtering algorithm on Spark, but I got stuck on an RDD transformation issue. I have my input RDD as this:

> ["John", "a", "5"], ["John", "b", "3"],["John", "c", "2"],["Mark", "a", "3"] ["Mark", "b", "4"] ["Lucy", "b", "2"] ["Lucy", "c", "5"]

In each RDD element, the first value is the user, second value is the product name ("a","b", or "c") and the third value is its rating.

I want to transform the input RDD by grouping by  name, then by combination of product, so my final result RDD will be

> [("a","b"),("5","2")] [("a","b"),("3","4")] [("a","c"),("5","2")]

In the above result, because both John and Mark have "rating" on both a and b, so I have two RDD elements with (a,b) as key, and their ratings as value. Only John has rating on both a and c, thus I only have one RDD element with (a,c) as key.

Comment: I'm a little confused by the phrase "if I input 'a'". Can you elaborate on this or post some code?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. It is not important at this moment, I deleted that line,

Comment: This is still not clear...

Comment: Share what you have done so far!

Comment: I am trying to find a pattern but the explanation is too superficial

Comment: Just added more explanation on the transformation, hope it helps.

Comment: Should the first element of the output have the value ("5","3")? Also would I  correct in saying that "Lucy" would generate (("b", "c"),("2", "5"))?

Comment: @RohanAletty Yes, both John and Lucy will generate (b,c) key, so we will have [(b,c),(3,2)] [(b,c),(2,5)]. But I only care about combinations with "a" in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like the following:

```
val keyedElems = rdd1.map { case (a, b, c) => (a, (b, c)) }
val groupedCombinations = keyedElems.groupByKey().flatMapValues(_.toList.combinations(2))
val productScoreCombinations = groupedCombinations.mapValues { case (elems: List[(String, String)]) => ((elems(0)._1, elems(1)._1), (elems(0)._2, elems(1)._2)) }.values
```

What we are doing here is keying your input dataset by user, producing an iterable list of (product, rating) by grouping by key, producing the 2-combinations of each list, flattening that list to put each combination into its own record, and finally reordering the elements to have the products and ratings in their own tuples.

When run locally in Spark, I'm seeing the following:

```
scala> val rdd1 = sc.parallelize(Array(("John", "a", "5"),("John", "b", "3"),("John", "c", "2"),("Mark", "a", "3"),("Mark", "b", "4"),("Lucy", "b", "2"),("Lucy", "c", "5")))
rdd1: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, String, String)] = ParallelCollectionRDD[0] at parallelize at <console>:21

scala> val rdd2 = rdd1.map { case (a, b, c) => (a, (b, c)) }
rdd2: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, (String, String))] = MapPartitionsRDD[1] at map at <console>:23

scala> val rdd3 = rdd2.groupByKey().flatMapValues(_.toList.combinations(2))
rdd3: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, List[(String, String)])] = MapPartitionsRDD[3] at flatMapValues at <console>:25

scala> val rdd4 = rdd3.mapValues { case (elems: List[(String, String)]) => ((elems(0)._1, elems(1)._1), (elems(0)._2, elems(1)._2)) }.values
rdd4: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[((String, String), (String, String))] = MapPartitionsRDD[7] at values at <console>:27

scala> rdd4.foreach(println)
...
((a,b),(3,4))
((b,c),(2,5))
((a,b),(5,3))
((a,c),(5,2))
((b,c),(3,2))
```

You can run a simple filter on this to find all rows with product "a".

(EDIT:)

I missed that you had tagged this as pyspark so I've updated with a python solution below (essentially mapped from the scala one above):

```
import itertools

keyedElems = input.map(lambda x: (x[0], (x[1], x[2])))
groupedCombinations = keyedElems.groupByKey().flatMapValues(lambda arr: itertools.combinations(arr, 2))
productScoreCombinations = groupedCombinations.mapValues(lambda elems: ((elems[0][0], elems[1][0]), (elems[0][1], elems[1][1]))).map(lambda x: x[1])
```

When I run the above code, I see the following in pyspark:

```
>>> input = sc.parallelize([("John", "a", "5"),("John", "b", "3"),("John", "c", "2"),("Mark", "a", "3"),("Mark", "b", "4"),("Lucy", "b", "2"),("Lucy", "c", "5")])
...
>>> productScoreCombinations.take(6)
...
[(('b', 'c'), ('2', '5')), (('a', 'b'), ('5', '3')), (('a', 'c'), ('5', '2')), (('b', 'c'), ('3', '2')), (('a', 'b'), ('3', '4'))]
```

Comment: Thanks. I am using pyspark, so I am trying to figure out your idea. One question, won't rdd.groupByKey() then flatMapValues() give out the same rdd?

Comment: To my understanding, you are grouping the user together, then find all products combination this user has. Output that products combination as key, and their respective rating as key? Is that correct?

Comment: @SYZ To your first question, if the identity function were passed to `flatMapValues()`, then yes. However, here we are passing a function that will create generate the combinations of the grouped tuples. To your second question, you are essentially right if you meant "respective rating as value" :)

Comment: Right, that is what I meant. Thank you very much